# Por que except no salta cuando el if statemant es false en la fuccion update_age?

Tags: python

Mi problema es con el try except. Estoy intentando que el except salte en el momento cuando introduzca otra cosa ca int. En mi codigo el except salta solo cuando self.estimated_insurance_cost() es accionada y da error por que no puedes multiplicar en mi ejemplo int con str.

Por favor explinqueme como resuelvo el problema.
Muchas gracias.

```
class Patient:
      def __init__(self, name, age, sex, bmi, num_of_children, smoker):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
        self.bmi = bmi
        self.num_of_children = num_of_children
        self.smoker = smoker
    
      # method used to calculate an estimation of the insurance cost

      def estimated_insurance_cost(self):
        estimated_cost = 250 * self.age - 128 * self.sex + 370 * self.bmi + 425 * self.num_of_children + 24000 * self.smoker - 12500
        print("{}'s estimated insurance costs is {} dollars.".format(self.name,estimated_cost))

    # method meant to update the age

      def update_age(self, new_age):
          if type(new_age) is 'int':
            self.age = new_age  
            print("{} is now {} years old.".format(self.name, self.age))
            self.estimated_insurance_cost()
    
    patient1 = Patient("John Doe", 25, 1, 22.2, 0, 0)
    #patient1.estimated_insurance_cost()
    # Try to catch error 
    try:
      patient1.update_age("age")
    except:
      print("Error! Please insert an integer")
```

Lo que sale :

```
John Doe is now age years old.
Error! Please insert an integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python no puede saber de la nada que el dato ingresado deberia de generar un error. Para lograr eso la forma correcta en tu función `update_age` sería:

```
  def update_age(self, new_age):
      # Notese que cambié por completo el condicional con el que evaluas el tipo de dato
      if isinstance(new_age, int):
          self.age = new_age  
          print("{} is now {} years old.".format(self.name, self.age))
          self.estimated_insurance_cost()
      else:
          raise ValueError("La edad debería ser un entero")
```

La forma correcta de saber de que tipo es un valor especifico sería la función [isinstance](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance), que recibe como primer argumento un objeto y como segundo el tipo o tupla de tipos que debería ser.

Para decirle a python que debe de mandar una excepción se usa la declaración [raise](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_raise.asp), que acepta como "argumento" el tipo de error y entre parentesis el mensaje a mostrar.

Para saber más sobre errores y excepciones, puedes leer la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la explicacion. Ahora todo es muy claro.

Comment: De nada YuSinn!